# What does "we were just popping off each other" mean?

Tags: british-english, phrasal-verbs

In an interview, when Paul McCartney talked about his memory with Michael Jackson:

> It was actually upstairs, here. In this office. Michael originally rang me, and said ‘do you want to make some hits?’ I didn’t know who it was, I didn’t recognise his voice at first, but I dug into it, and then I said ‘yeah, sure.’ He came along, we agreed to meet in here, at the piano upstairs. We just sat around with a guitar, at the piano, and we just sort of went ‘what shall we do?’. We just started, and it came very easily. I was quite excited to write with him, he was excited to write with me, so **we were just popping off each other**. We just did it, it was a very short session, and we were in the same room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To pop** [off someone] *(informal)* always positive (transitive and intransitive) = **to exchange innovative ideas very quickly especially in a way in which each member of the conversation/action is  inspired by the other(s)**

Very similar to **bounce** [ideas] off someone/each other but more lively.

Compare

OED:
**3.e. pop** v. intransitive. **To occur in a lively or exciting manner; to bustle with activity or agitation; to be filled or alive with.**

1998   Independent 19 May i. 18/6   *You only have to walk through Soho to feel that something is popping.*

Comment: Perfect. Would you minding telling me where can I find this definition ? I cannot even google anything close to this definition

Comment: No, I can't find it either. It is very informal/colloquial and now not particularly common. I seem to remember it best from the late 90s/early 2000s and mainly from contexts such as you have given.